# Seeing if a Password is equal to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

So I am pretty new to JavaScript, and I have this form that checks if your password is equal to a variable, but once I made the password input, a password type, it will no longer say they are equal.

```
<script>
    function log(f) {
        if ((f.username.value == "ben")&&(f.password.value == "password")) {
            alert("success");
        } else {
            alert("failure);
        }
    }
</script>

<form name = "f">
    Username:
    <input type="text" name = "username">
    Password:
    <input type = "password" name = "password">
    <br>
    <input type = "button" value = "Enter" onClick = "log(f)">
    <br>Result:
    <input type = "text" name = "result">
</form>
```

Comment: just a note, if you're validating a password in javascript. i'd simply have to right click and view source to see the password and bypass this security measure.

Comment: This is worse than no security since you'll *think* there's something going on here, but really it's like a locked door with no wall. This has to be done server-side for it to actually do something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. However there is a syntax error here: 
 `alert("failure);` you are missing the closinh `"` . Change it to `alert("failure");`

You can check it here [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xgeorgekx/mhzzq5bu/12/)